# How can i do pl/sql Update with join

Tags: plsql, sql-update

how can i update a table column from another table. here is my code :

```
update table1 hn 
set  hn.changeColumn=es.changeColumn
from table1 hn
inner join table2 es on es.x=hn.xand es.rol_id=hn.rol_id
where hn.x= es.x and hn.rol_id = es.rol_id
```

i wanna set table1's column(changeColumn) values with table2's column(changeColumn) values

how can i do this. thanks

Comment: plsql is related to Oracle only but the syntax you are using is for SQL-SERVER. Please tag your question for correct DBSM.

Comment: i wonder or i wanna learn this in pl/sql sir is it problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert this query to Oracle, You need a MERGE INTO statement -

```
MREGE INTO table1 hn 
USING table2 es
ON (es.x=hn.x and es.rol_id=hn.rol_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
     UPDATE
     SET  hn.changeColumn=es.changeColumn
```

Answer (score 1):

One valid way to write this query on Oracle would be:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET changeColumn = (SELECT t2.changeColumn
                    FROM table2 t2
                    WHERE t1.x = t2.x AND t1.rol_id = t2.rol_id);
```

This assumes that your join condition would only generate at most a single pair of mstching records from the self join.  If not, then we would have to modify the logic.